# Editors returning contents with html tags

Tags: javascript, html, django

At first I thought it was the wysiwyg editors fault I had to try different ones. But turns out they all return contents with html tag...so it must be me. I'm using https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor  and this also returns with html tag. ex: if I type hello it returns `<p>hello</p>` so I tried safe filtering and some other filtering but none of them works. how do I fix this? Thanks in advance

```
{% block content %}
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form |crispy|safe }}


     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I also tried `{{form|safe}}` which doesn't work...and I want to use crispy as well.

Comment: "if I type `hello` it returns `hello`" What do you want to return?

Comment: @MaihanNijat it's suppose to be <p>hello</p> but SO takes <p>as paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read the docs I've found this one:

```
data = django_wysiwyg.clean_html(data)
```

Try it, I hope it works...

**EDIT:**

> {{ form |crispy|safe }}

This outputs the RAW Html, this is what you don't want I guess...

Comment: Hello where'd you see data = django_wysiwyg.clean_html(data)
?? can't find that in anywhere, and where should I put that?html?